# Postgres Create Table As Select query with multiple left outer joins produces duplicated data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have several tables that have a UDID (unique ID) and some other information. I am trying to combine these tables such that every UDID appears once in the final table. The data in all of my input tables looks correct and makes good theoretical sense. However, when I look at output table I'm seeing the same data over and over.

Here is the query:

```
create table roi_wide_ss_gen_all as
select a.udid, a.src, a.tm8,a.tm7,a.tm6,a.tm5,a.tm4,a.tm3,a.tm2,a.tm1, a.t1, a.t2, a.t3, a.t4, a.t5,a.t6,a.t7,a.t8 
       , pf_m, female, asam, pf_50, pf_150, pf_250, pf_251 
from roi_wide_ss_gen a
    left outer join roi_wide_ss_gen_m b on (a.udid = b.udid)
    left outer join roi_wide_ss_gen_f c on (a.udid = c.udid)
    left outer join roi_wide_ss_gen_k d on (a.udid = d.udid) 
    left outer join roi_wide_ss_gen_50 e on (a.udid = e.udid)  
    left outer join roi_wide_ss_gen_150 f on (a.udid = f.udid) 
    left outer join roi_wide_ss_gen_250 g on (a.udid = g.udid)  
    left outer join roi_wide_ss_gen_251 h on (a.udid = h.udid)
    left outer join roi_wide_ss_gen_as i on (a.udid = i.udid)
;
```

Here are the first few rows of the output table:

```
             udid src tm8 tm7 tm6 tm5 tm4 tm3 tm2 tm1 t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 pf_m female asam pf_50 pf_150 pf_250 pf_251
 2b4821ecf223b1f6   1   0   0   0   0   4   6   2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0      1       1     0      0      0      0
 2b4821ecf223b1f6   1   0   0   0   0   4   6   2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0      1       1     0      0      0      0
 2b4821ecf223b1f6   1   0   0   0   0   4   6   2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0      1       1     0      0      0      0
 2b4821ecf223b1f6   1   0   0   0   0   4   6   2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0      1       1     0      0      0      0
 2b4821ecf223b1f6   1   0   0   0   0   4   6   2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0      1       1     0      0      0      0
```

if I let this continue for 100 rows then the data does eventually change a bit, like this

```
2b4821ecf223b1f6   1   0   0   0   0   4   6   2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0      1       1     0      0      0      0         
2b4821ecf223b1f6   1   0   0   0   0   4   6   2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0      1       1     0      0      0      0                         
a6ce599b8344bb4c   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    1      1       0     0      0      0      0
3f1448b00f8d8031   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0    1      1       0     0      0      0      0
fca0bd81bdc66de5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1    1      1       0     0      0      0      0
fca0bd81bdc66de5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1    1      1       0     0      0      0      0
```

but it's still not 1 row per UDID like it should be for most UDID's. I could've sworn I had this working correctly in the past, and yet...

Comment: Does any table has duplicate `udid` ?

Comment: Cheapest way to find out: comment them out one-by-one (or half of them)

Comment: @wildplasser this exactly my way of finding such a things

Comment: If there are any one to many relationships at play here you have to first decide which records you actually want from each table.  The simplest ones to get would be the min or max value, but that might not meet your requirements.

Comment: `and makes good theoretical sense` In theory, theory and practice are the same. In practice they are not. @Roman that is my way of _building_ the query in the first place: start with the skeleton, add the meat later.

Comment: @wildplasser damn, and that's one of my favourite phrases about theory!!! :)

Comment: Do the tables have any set of keys which could serve as a candidate key? Maybe even a PRIMARY KEY? Just asking... @Roman: the other one is: "Good judgement stems from experience. Experience stems from bad judgement."

Comment: Q: Does any table have dup udid? A: No. They did before I grouped them at an earlier stage but the input tables look perfectly correct.

Comment: if you have no unique constraint on udid, check `select udid from ... group by udid having count(*) > 1` on your tables

Comment: @wildplasser: comment out what, tables? ok I will try it, though I looked at all the tables and they look perfect.

Comment: are you sure the type of `udid` column is similar in all tables?

Comment: If you really get duplicate rows, you can use `distinct` to get rid of them.

Comment: Comment out all the (bcdefgh) LEFT JOINS, plus all the fields (the second line, I _think_, since they were not fully qualified by an alias) that they delever. Then add them one-by-one (or better)

Comment: @Jason At least one of the tables must have duplicate `udid`. Otherwise there will be only one row in the result.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think he should find a cause of duplication before hiding it with `distinct`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `distinct` in a query in most cases is a sign of design flaw. It is a bad idea to use it to mask mistakes.

Comment: I'm so dumb. "if you have no unique constraint on udid, check select udid from ... group by udid having count(*) > 1 on your tables " was the answer. Can you please post it as an answer so that I can give you a green checkmark? Thank you all very much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're should be a duplicate `udid` in one of your tables - if you have no unique constraint on `udid`, check result of

```
select udid from ... group by udid having count(*) > 1
```

on your tables to find out

Comment: Thanks again. Just to be 100% accurate -- I added the group by.... having count(*) > 1 ; to the final query, but the results are beautiful and this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: hmm.. What I've meant is try to FIND duplicate udid in your table by grouping and selecting data where `count(*) > 1`, not to add `group by` to your final query...

Comment: I noticed that after the fact and I can go back and look for a duplicate in an input table... I guess I'll do that as soon as I get time... but the results look beautiful if I just add that to the final query...

Comment: ok, but I've warned you :) it's better to do it earler than later, because it looks like there're duplicates in your table and you're thinking that there're not, and it could lead to some unexpected results sometimes